# Variable set to call a function

Tags: python

*I hope this question doesn't seem too naive or silly, but I would just like to get  a definite answer as confirmation.*

Is it possible to set a variable to call to a function?

i.e

```
def func():
    print "test"

var = [something magical + func]
```

then if you had typed/used just `var` it would output `test`?

In other words, is there an alternate way to calling a function without the use of parenthesis if it never requires (or accepts) arguments [in Python]?

I am assuming this isn't possible as you always required to use"()" to call a function, but I am curious if there might be any exceptions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the @property decorator work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

Comment: This question isn't meant to be related to decorators

Comment: You would use the `@property` decorator on the appropriate class to type `var` and have it output `test`.

Comment: Do you want it in the list?

Comment: Do you have a practical use case for this?

Comment: It wasn't meant to be interpreted as a list, just brackets (and {} is dictionaries and () tuples, so I didn't know what else to use).... I'll flag to delete this question as it seems the answer is no, but my question is misinterpretted

Comment: @MarkN, yes the answer to your question is simply no.

Comment: [*"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) What benefit would there be to providing alternative syntax for calling a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In general, no**. With the exception of [properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work) as mentioned in comments, you will always need to apply a parameter list (even if it's empty `()`) to actually call the function. Otherwise, you're not *calling* the function, but *referencing the function itself as a value*.

You can easily reproduce this on Python's command line interpreter:

```
>>> def func():
...     return "foo"
... 
>>> func() # Actually call the function; statement returns the function's return value
'foo'
>>> func # Reference the function as value; statement returns *the function itself*
<function func at 0x7f2c7a65b938>

>>> var = func # Assign the function value to another variable
>>> var # Now "var" references the same function as "func"...
<function func at 0x7f2c7a65b938>
>>> var() # ...and can also be called as a function
'foo'
>>>
```

Comment: This is what I was referring to, thank you. I was just curious as to whether there might have been another possible way to call a function without following the normal use of parenthesis [in Python]..

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking it:

```
def func():
    print "test"

var = func
var() # calls func()
```

In python, functions are objects, so you can assign `var` to the function `func` and now it is a reference to `func`. You can also assign variables to class *definitions*, because those are objects too:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 1

B = A # B is the same class type as A
myA = B() # constructs an A
print(myA.data) # prints "1"
```

Comment: So in other words, no?

Comment: Not without the () syntax.

Answer (score 2):

For command line usage, there is another trick: `__repr__`.
I use it to call a function just by one single character.

Say you want to call `f()`:

```
>>> class OneCharFunc(object):
...   def __repr__(self):
...     f()
...     return ''
...
>>> n=OneCharFunc()
>>> n
```

Comment: I have made a *decorator* out of this idea: `@Without()` \   `def f(): print "Hey"` \   Call by  `f`  from command line interpreter. https://github.com/zellerede/utilities/blob/master/util/wp.py

Comment: Say what!? This is some crazy python magic. Berci is a true wizard :)

Answer (score 1):

The `@property` decorator allows you to disguise methods as ordinary attributes. This is useful for things that should be a calculated value, e.g. time remaining in a countdown timer. This ensures a dynamically-updated value for that variable each time it's referenced, because it's really a method call.

```
>>> class O(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.x = 0
...     @property
...     def x_is_negative(self):
...             return self.x < 0
...
>>> a = O()
>>> a.x_is_negative
False
>>> a.x = -1
>>> a.x_is_negative
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> def hello_world(name):
...   print('hello', name)

>>> hello_world('luiz')
hello luiz

>>> hello_world
<function hello_world at 0x0000023C48FC50D0>

>>> a=[hello_world, 'luiz']
>>> a[0](a[1])
hello luiz

>>> type(a[0])
<class 'function'>
>>> type(a[1])
<class 'str'>
```